# Rails use base64 with user id in url?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, base64

I've been looking into the benefits of using base64 in urls and for files and I like the idea, and I can't seem to find anywhere to start. I have played around on the console encoding my picture urls too base64 which works okay(I can access it in the html decoding it in the view),

My question would be how would I do this for urls? Instead of using 1.. 2.. 3 for my users, I would like to try and use base64 for the 'users/1' instead so it would be something like 'users/U3Rvcm1WaXBlcg' for example

Comment: I think you need to explain more fully what you want to achieve, `StormViper` is not `base64` - you would consider the base64 representation of a string to be essentially random letters.

Comment: sorry I didn't think about that - I did mean base64 such as U3Rvcm1WaXBlcg

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly, lets take discord as an wonderful example, you can copy someone's userID and then it in a base64 encoder, and boom you have the first part of someone's token. The ID in decoded is someone's token.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).